# Looping through cURL json array result

Tags: php

I have been trying to do this for awhile. I have a request to an api using cURL. For the moment I can execute the cURL function and encode it with json. I can print_r() an element of the array which gives me back one result. However I have a return from the api of 25 elements of which I need to return back just the id of the 25 elements. I have included a var_dump() of the array to give you a screen shot of the array. The list iterates to 24 elements. I need the 25 Id's

Below is my code

```
<?php 


$url = 'https://api.getbase.com/v2/lead_sources?sort_by=name:desc';


//Initiate cURL.
$chbase_user = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($chbase_user, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($chbase_user, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4','Accept: application/json','Authorization: Bearer inserted here')); 


$result_base_user = curl_exec($chbase_user);

$data_result_base_user = json_decode($result_base_user,true);






echo '<pre>';
print_r($data_result_base_user['items'][0]['data']['id']);
var_dump($data_result_base_user );// Below is the result of this

?>



array(2) {
["items"]=>
array(25) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["data"]=>
    array(6) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(154808)
      ["created_at"]=>
      string(20) "2015-11-09T09:25:55Z"
      ["updated_at"]=>
      string(20) "2018-03-08T16:43:31Z"
      ["name"]=>
      string(17) "X - Zopim IM Chat"
      ["creator_id"]=>
      int(675478)
      ["resource_type"]=>
      string(4) "lead"
    }
    ["meta"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["type"]=>
      string(6) "source"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through the `$data_result_base_user['items']`, save ids in array and return that array

```
$ids = array();

foreach ($data_result_base_user['items'] as $key => $value) {
    $ids[]=$value['data']['id']; // assuming all element have same structure
}

return $ids;
```